# css jquery animation doesn't run fully - 2 weird bugs

Tags: jquery, html, css

**FIDDLE**
http://jsfiddle.net/zuhloobie/t9x723tq/10/

**GOALS**
(a) flip from blue to gray if entering hover and staying on hover
(b) flip from gray back to blue if hover is left
(c) if you enter hover and leave hover really quickly, run the full animation (blue to gray and back to blue)

These "sorta" work in my fiddle, but it's buggy...

**2 BUGS/QUESTIONS**
(1) If you enter hover from the left side of the div, it flips to back side and stays as intended, but it doesn't finish the animation and flip back to front after leaving hover. *How to fix this?*

(2) If you enter hover from the top, right, or bottom of the div, it does not flip to the back side, but it does run the entire animation after leaving hover. *How to fix this*?

**JQUERY**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".bar").hover(function() 
    { 
        $(this).bind("mouseover mouseout transitionend webkitTransitionEnd oTransitionEnd", function() {
            $(this).find(".vFlipper").css({"transition":".4s","transform-style":"preserve-3d","position":"relative"});
            $(this).find(".vertical.vFlip .vFlipper").css({"transform":"rotateX(-180deg)","background-color":"#999999"});
        });
    }, 
    function() 
    { 
        $(this).bind("mouseover mouseout transitionend webkitTransitionEnd oTransitionEnd", function() {
            $(this).find(".vFlipper").css({"transition":".4s","transform-style":"preserve-3d","position":"relative"});
            $(this).find(".vertical.vFlip .vFlipper").css({"transform":"rotateX(0deg)","background-color":"#4FAEDD"});
        });
    }); 
});
```

**CSS**

```
#container {width:80%; margin:0 auto;}
.bar {width:50%; margin:30px auto 0 30px; height:50px}
.bar ul {list-style:none;}
.bar > ul > li > a{display:block; padding:10px; text-decoration:none;}
.bar > ul > li > a:hover {text-decoration:none;}
.vFlip {perspective:140px; -webkit-perspective:140px; perspective-origin:center; -webkit-perspective-origin:center;}
.vertical.vFlip {position:relative;}
.vertical.vFlip .vFlipper {background-color:#4FAEDD;}
```

Thank you for any help.

Comment: Did you consider using CSS-3D transforms for that?

Comment: I thought I was? To be honest, I've gone through so many iterations to satisfy my goal that this is the closest I've gotten it to "work" :/ Do you mean transforms instead of transitions?

Comment: @BSMP - really? Grr. I'm still getting both bugs on Chrome v41.0.2272.118 m. This is driving me bonkers.

Comment: @chris - Sorry, I double checked and it was just that I was mousing out fast enough to not get the error. I did have the first one happen when I tried it again. So I'm at least seeing the same problems you are.

Comment: +1 for the challenging question. can you take a look at my answer it doesn't use any library. The currently accepted answer seems to leave some items with gray background even when mouse is no longer over them.

Comment: @NithishThomas - see my comment on your answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update: http://jsfiddle.net/t9x723tq/22/

Alright, this seems to be what you want. I chose to use a JavaScript library (TweenLite) instead of CSS, so that it is cleaner and more compatible. I also stripped the code that was irrelevant to the animation.

http://jsfiddle.net/t9x723tq/17/

```js
//using TweenLite.set() takes care of all vendor-prefixes
TweenLite.set(".barWrapper", {
  perspective: 500
});
TweenLite.set(".bar", {
  transformStyle: "preserve-3d"
});
TweenLite.set(".back", {
  rotationX: -180
});
TweenLite.set([".back", ".front"], {
  backfaceVisibility: "hidden"
});


var mouseover = false;
var hovering = false;

$(".barWrapper").mouseover(
  function() {
    mouseover = true;
    TweenLite.to($(this).find(".bar"), 0.5, {
      rotationX: 180,
      ease: Expo.easeOut,
      onComplete: function() {
        if (!mouseover)
          TweenLite.to(this.target, 0.5, {
            rotationX: 0,
            ease: Expo.easeOut
          });
        else hovering = true;
      }
    });
  }
);

$(".barWrapper").mouseleave(
  function() {
    mouseover = false;
    if (hovering) {
      hovering = false;
      TweenLite.to($(this).find(".bar"), 0.5, {
        rotationX: 0,
        ease: Expo.easeOut
      });
    }
  }
);
```

```css
.barWrapper {
  margin: 5px;
  display: inline-block;
}
.bar {
  width: 300px;
  height: 50px;
  position: relative;
}
.front {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #4FAEDD;
}
.back {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: grey;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/1.16.1/plugins/CSSPlugin.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/1.16.1/easing/EasePack.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/1.16.1/TweenLite.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
  <div class="barWrapper">
    <div class="bar">
      <div class="front">Front</div>
      <div class="back">Back</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="barWrapper">
    <div class="bar">
      <div class="front">Front</div>
      <div class="back">Back</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="barWrapper">
    <div class="bar">
      <div class="front">Front</div>
      <div class="back">Back</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="barWrapper">
    <div class="bar">
      <div class="front">Front</div>
      <div class="back">Back</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="barWrapper">
    <div class="bar">
      <div class="front">Front</div>
      <div class="back">Back</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes, that's pretty close...but a problem with stripping a lot of my code out means I cannot take my simplified case fiddle which we are working on here and use it in my larger case fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/zuhloobie/21b2r35n/2/. In that fiddle, I want to keep everything, but have the flipping animation as what I've described here.

Comment: Well, `<div class="front">Front</div><div class="back">Back</div>` can contain anything.

Comment: Did you see my larger case fiddle? The front/back DIVs aren't the issue.  The issue is the accordion to which I'm applying this animation. In your fiddle, which works great, should also provide the current accordion sequence in my larger case fiddle. So this would be the proper sequence: 1) hover blue flips it to gray, 2) click on gray and accordion slides down per my larger case fiddle, 3) click on gray again and accordion slides up, 4) leave hover of gray and it flips back to blue. It has to do 1-4, while also running the full animation if hover/unhover is done quickly ("c" in goals).

Comment: @chris The updated answer fulfills all the requirements in this question. If you need help applying this to your larger case, let me know.

Comment: Sorry if I'm being a pain in the butt. So hard to describe in words. I took my larger case fiddle and simplified it to the fiddle in this post. Once the simplified case is fixed, then I can apply it back to my larger case fiddle.

Comment: You are correct - it does solve the requirements in this question. Applying it to my larger case is the issue. I feel like since my simplified case is now completely different with your fixed code...it won't work if I apply it to the larger case. Thank you for your patience and hanging in there with me.

Comment: You can move the `ul` (drawer) inside the `.barWrapper` above. Do you want me to show you how? Animating with JS gives more control because you can use logic, unlike CSS. Would you still want an implementation in CSS?

Comment: Yeah, it looks like I'm stuck :( If you don't mind helping, I'd appreciate it quite a bit. Implementation-wise, I just want it to work how I envision it, but I prefer JS. I think the mixture of CSS and JS was giving me some of my issues.

Comment: How does this look? http://jsfiddle.net/t9x723tq/18/ There's a bug there, though. The `mouseover` and `hovering` flags are global. They'll have to be attached with each bar object to avoid conflicts.

Comment: OMG! Yes - so close! Only issue I can see is that if you move your mouse from the top of the output frame to the bottom and then back up again (sometimes it takes more than once) in fiddle, sometimes one or two of the orange bars will stay on gray (the back state). In Chrome. Are you seeing that?

Comment: I did not refresh my page to see your edited comment about the bugs before I wrote my comment, sorry.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/74660/discussion-between-user2570380-and-chris).

Comment: My final public thank you (even though I'm breaking guideline rules again): thank you so much for your help. Truly is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you require http://jsfiddle.net/f4x4uzu1/2/

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var customAnimator = function(this_var) {
    var myCustomAnimator = {};
    myCustomAnimator.var_this = this_var;
    myCustomAnimator.inside = false;
    myCustomAnimator.onHoverIn = function() {
      myCustomAnimator.inside = true;
      $(this).find(".vFlipper").css({
        "transition": ".4s",
        "transform-style": "preserve-3d",
        "position": "relative"
      });
      $(this).find(".vertical.vFlip .vFlipper").css({
        "transform": "rotateX(-180deg)",
        "background-color": "#999999"
      });
      $(this).one('webkitTransitionEnd otransitionend oTransitionEnd msTransitionEnd transitionend',
        function(e) {
          if (myCustomAnimator.inside) {
            console.info('handler attached');
            $(this).one('mouseleave', myCustomAnimator.onHoverOutCallback);
          } else {
            console.info('calling  callback directly');
            myCustomAnimator.onHoverOutCallback();
          }
        });

    };

    myCustomAnimator.onHoverOut = function() {
      myCustomAnimator.inside = false;
    };

    myCustomAnimator.onHoverOutCallback = function() {
      console.info('call back called');
      $(myCustomAnimator.var_this).find(".vFlipper").css({
        "transition": ".4s",
        "transform-style": "preserve-3d",
        "position": "relative"
      });
      $(myCustomAnimator.var_this).find(".vertical.vFlip .vFlipper").css({
        "transform": "rotateX(0deg)",
        "background-color": "#4FAEDD"
      });

    };
    return myCustomAnimator;
  };

  $(".bar").each(function() {
    var myAnimator = customAnimator(this);
    $(this).hover(myAnimator.onHoverIn, myAnimator.onHoverOut);
  });
});
```

```css
#container {
  width: 80%;
  margin: 0 0;
}
.bar {
  width: 50%;
  margin: 30px 0;
}
.bar ul {
  list-style: none;
}
.bar > ul > li > a {
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  height: 40px;
}
.bar > ul > li > a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
}
.vFlip {
  perspective: 140px;
  -webkit-perspective: 140px;
  perspective-origin: center;
  -webkit-perspective-origin: center;
}
/*.vFlipper {transition:.4s; transform-style:preserve-3d; position:relative;}*/

.vertical.vFlip {
  position: relative;
}
.vertical.vFlip .vFlipper {
  background-color: #4FAEDD;
}
.vertical.vFlip:hover .vFlipper {
  /*transform:rotateX(-180deg) scaleY(-1); background-color:#999999;*/
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
  <div class="bar">
    <ul>
      <li class="vertical vFlip" ontouchstart="this.classList.toggle('hover');"> <a class="vFlipper" href="#" onclick="return false;">&nbsp;</a>

      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="bar">
    <ul>
      <li class="vertical vFlip" ontouchstart="this.classList.toggle('hover');"> <a class="vFlipper" href="#" onclick="return false;">&nbsp;</a>

      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="bar">
    <ul>
      <li class="vertical vFlip" ontouchstart="this.classList.toggle('hover');"> <a class="vFlipper" href="#" onclick="return false;">&nbsp;</a>

      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="bar">
    <ul>
      <li class="vertical vFlip" ontouchstart="this.classList.toggle('hover');"> <a class="vFlipper" href="#" onclick="return false;">&nbsp;</a>

      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="bar">
    <ul>
      <li class="vertical vFlip" ontouchstart="this.classList.toggle('hover');"> <a class="vFlipper" href="#" onclick="return false;">&nbsp;</a>

      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

-

Comment: This is also a great answer - thank you for sharing, but I'm going with the first answer given. Have a great day!

Answer (score 0):

You are binding multiple things to the same events.

### Updated

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var inside = 0;
    var transistion = 0;
    $(".bar").bind("mouseover touchstart focus", function () {

        $(this).find(".vFlipper").css({
            "transition": ".4s",
                "transform-style": "preserve-3d",
                "position": "relative"
        });
        $(this).find(".vertical.vFlip .vFlipper").css({
            "transform": "rotateX(-180deg)",
                "background-color": "#999999"
        });
        inside = 1;
    });

    $(".bar").bind("mouseout touchend blur", function () {
        inside = 0;
        if (transistion == 1 && inside == 0){
                $(this).find(".vFlipper").css({
                    "transition": ".4s",
                        "transform-style": "preserve-3d",
                        "position": "relative"
                });
                $(this).find(".vertical.vFlip .vFlipper").css({
                    "transform": "rotateX(0deg)",
                        "background-color": "#4FAEDD"
                });
         }
    });
    
    $(".bar").bind("transitionend webkitTransitionEnd oTransitionEnd", function () {
            transistion = 1;
        });
});
```

**DEMO:** [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hopkins_matt/t9x723tq/15/)

Comment: Thanks for responding. I have to bind them with transitionend and mouseover/mouseout in order for it to complete the full animation. Using your code, does not satisfy the "Goal" in the OP :/ It only completes half the animation.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something... In my fiddle, when you hove the div it flips to the back, and when you leave the div it flips back to the front.

Comment: Hover and unhover really quick - it doesn't run the full blue to gray to blue animation, it only runs as long as it is being hovered. In your fiddle, if you are only hovering for a millisecond, it never flips to gray. The goal is to (a) have it run from blue to gray if hover is kept, (b) run from gray back to blue if hover is left, (c) run "a" and "b" (the full animation) if you hover and leave hover quickly.

Comment: I edited my original post to clarify "Goals" a bit more. Sorry for any confusion.

Comment: Ok I made a few changes. See if that does what you want.

Comment: Thank you for your edits, but it still isn't accomplishing "c" in "Goals". It does "a" and "b", but not "c". Here's a good test: move your mouse fairly quickly from the very top of the output panel down to the bottom (so you pass over each blue bar). Each one should flip to gray and back to blue. Yours only starts to flip from blue, but then resets on unhover. See my fiddle - "c" is the only thing that works, LOL. I can't get "a" and "b" to work consistently with entering hover from any side.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I would do it with CSS3.
I'm sorry if it doesn't work in all browsers, I checked only chrome:
http://jsfiddle.net/dp4yxbL3/1/

```css
body {
    -webkit-perspective: 140px;
    -moz-perspective: 140px;
    perspective: 140px;
    -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

.flipContainer {
    width:170px;
    height:40px;
    margin:10px;
}

.flip {
    width:170px;
    height:40px;
    -webkit-perspective: 140px;
    -moz-perspective: 140px;
    perspective: 140px;
    -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -webkit-transition:all .5s;
    -moz-transition:all .5s;
    -o-transition:all .5s;
    transition:all .5s;
}

.flip div {
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    width:170px;
    height:40px;
    line-height:40px;
    padding:0 5px;
    box-sizing:border-box;
    -webkit-backface-visibility:hidden;
    -moz-backface-visibility:hidden;
    backface-visibility:hidden;
    
}

.front {
    background:#ccc;
}

.back {
    background:#4FAEDD;
    -webkit-transform:rotateX(180deg);
    -moz-transform:rotateX(180deg);
    -ms-transform:rotateX(180deg);
    -o-transform:rotateX(180deg);
    transform:rotateX(180deg);
}

.flipContainer:hover .flip {
    -webkit-transform:rotateX(180deg);
    -moz-transform:rotateX(180deg);
    -ms-transform:rotateX(180deg);
    -o-transform:rotateX(180deg);
    transform:rotateX(180deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="flipContainer">
    <div class="flip">
        <div class="front">
            maybe some front text?
        </div>
        <div class="back">
            maybe some back text?
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="flipContainer">
    <div class="flip">
        <div class="front">
            maybe some front text?
        </div>
        <div class="back">
            maybe some back text?
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="flipContainer">
    <div class="flip">
        <div class="front">
            maybe some front text?
        </div>
        <div class="back">
            maybe some back text?
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for responding. Your fiddle is only running half the animation. It is flipping to gray on hover. It is flipping back to blue when leaving hover...but it is not running the full animation - if you hover/leave hover quickly it stays on gray. Please see my updated/edited "Goals" in original post.